# Deparsing XML into multiple tables

Tags: python, sql, r, xml

Are there tools/packages for quick extracting from a nested XML to one or multiple tables/data.tables?

Assume I'm working with XML files in the following example format:

```
<root>
    <report>
        <summary>
        ...
        </summary>
        <history>
            <yr id="0" value="2014">
                <month id="0" value=""/>
                ...
            </yr>
            <yr id="1" value="2015">
            ...
            </yr>
        <updates>
            <update id="1">
            ...
            </update>
        </updates>
    </report>
</root>
```

It seems the easiest way would be to extract these nested blocks to separate tables (databases or files, whatever actually), and when necessary, join the data on the same report ID. However, as not having worked with XML's at all, I don't know any tools that could easily do that, while at the same time adding various ID's when necessary and keeping them unique.

One way is to write something by hand, but it feels that there should be tools/packages made for such (auto) deparsing (R package XML does a great job deparsing everything to a super flat structure without specifying any xpaths, but it becomes tedious trying to cast it to something cleaner). What are the best tools/packages for that? I'm comfortable in simpler languages as R/python, but it doesn't really matter if it gets the job done.

Bonus question: are there tools that could adapt to change of XML and form new tables when a previously unseen field is added?

Would be grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: The xml module offers a few alternatives. I would suggest to start with ElementTree. You should be able to get something running quickly when orienting on the given examples.

Comment: @guidot thanks for the pointer, seems promising, will have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want the output of your processing to be. However, XSLT and XQuery both provide simple high-level declarative ways of achieving the kind of task you are describing, and both are widely used. If you supply a more concrete example with desired output, then I'm sure we can suggest the kind of code that would be needed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I wasn't sure about asking for a concrete solution for a concrete problem since I'm still looking for the best direction to start at. *I think* the goal is to store those XML's into separate files/tables for easy querying. So far the current starting point was [this example of using libxml2](https://rud.is/rpubs/xml2power/), which with slight modification allows for quick and simple extraction of data to tables, requiring to run, i.e., only  ``xtrct_df(doc,'updates')``. This doesn't extract deeper-nested levels, but is a decent starting point so far.